# Detect graph from images

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, graph

I have set of images in which I want to separate graphs from others. I am looking at OpenCV but since I don't have any experience in image processing I don't know what technique or set of techniques should be applied in order to get this done.

I need to know the techniques of image processing for this task.

Sample Graphs are follows:
[image: Graph 1]
[image: Graph 2]
[image: Graph 3]
[image: Graph 4]

Other images can be of any type.. for e.g.
[image: Other Image 1]
[image: Other Image 2]
[image: Other Image 3]
[image: Other Image 2]

Thanks,

Jawad.

Comment: Could you show some of the images?

Comment: Please upload some images to show your point.  Also, which OpenCV interface are you using? Python, Java or C++?

Comment: I am looking at OpenCV C++ interface. However, I am open to use any technology that can be used with C#.